# How to get runtime id of html control sencha touch 2?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to get the runtime id (like, ext-element-100) of html control id in sencha control using sencha touch 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getId()`, that's exactly for this.
Documentation here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-getId

Comment: No.actually what I need is runtime html control id.not the sencha control id.getId() returns the sencha control id.but really inside sencha control there is a basic html controls like input type=text, select,etc.. id of those controls are auto generated by sencha touch framework.